# Ubuntu Touch: Ubuntu Online Accounts - where is the information stored?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, online-accounts, privacy

I use the MX4 with UT OTA-9.

If I start system settings > user accounts or e.g. the preinstalled Twitter-App I'm directed to "Ubuntu Online Accounts". Where is the data stored, I entered there? Local on my phone or in "the cloud"? Is it the same service as Ubuntu One (https://login.ubuntu.com/+login)? Where are the server located?

Answer (score 0):

The data is stored locally on your phone. Most of the account data is stored in the SQLite database file located in `~/.config/libaccounts-glib/accounts.db`, while ACLs (access control lists, that is the list of apps authorized to use an account) are stored in `~/.config/signond/signon.db` and passwords in `~/.config/signond/signon-secrets.db`.

The last file does not exist on the Unity7 desktop, where passwords are stored in the GNOME keyring instead.